# Why Task does not start without Wait

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

When I create a Task :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   // var testClient =
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            TaskClient();
        }); 
}  

public static void TaskClient()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
}
```

But this does not start the Console Write Untill I wait for the task!!!

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                TaskClient();
            }).Wait();
```

Why do we need to call Wait , When I am already starting the thread using `StartNew`

Comment: What happens after the loop?  Does the program end?

Comment: The program is probably ending. The "wait" allows the tasks to finish (writing to the console) before the program exits. The task *is* starting, you're just not waiting for it to do anything without the wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vcsjones has to be right. You don't see the result because program ended and window was closed.

I've tried your code and if I run the program from cmd, without debugger I can see the correct output. To make it a little more meaningful I've added another `Console.WriteLine` at the end of `Main` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // var testClient =
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        TaskClient();
    });
}

Console.WriteLine("End of program execution.");
```

Returns:

```
End of program execution.
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
```

As you can see, it works just fine.

If you want to wait with further execution untill all tasks are done, you can use `Task.WaitAll` static method:

```
var tasks = new Task[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // var testClient =
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    TaskClient();
                });
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```